# Way to Queue messages in .net Web API Rest Service

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, message-queue

So here is the scenario .

I have a REST Service designed with .Net Web API that has controllers calling oracle procedures via the oracle.dataaccess dll and providing some formatted response to end users.

This service has lately been getting heavily hit and that has resulted in connection timeout exceptions.

Here comes the odd part of the problem.

The issue at hand is quite readily handled if i use "proper" connection string parameters like **maxpoolsize**

The strange part is that the users of the Rest services do not want to let the oracle database they are using allow more than 5 connections at a time to the Rest services. Which in turn is causing the issue. Their claim is that the services are actually not using the ones in the pool. 
I am pretty sure that that is not the case.
At any rate with this handicap i am having to consider some other workaround to the problem.

Is there a way i can stream these values to the file system and then use some other tool to continuously look at the values and insert them into the database.
This way i can quickly just dump everything to the queue and let the user know that it is being taken care of.
Something like the Apache Active MQ.

Comment: Have you tried by increasing value for Connection Timeout property in connection string? Also you can check the Request Timeout value for Client  (like RestSharp or HTTP Client)? You might not have set it and default value is not long enough in some cases and due to that connection timeout is happening.

Comment: Yeah well i have suggested increasing the connection timeout but we cant do that either. I am looking for some intermediary service that does this.

Comment: You can go for open source [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) message queue but will probably need more work and time - if you haven't used earlier.